# Display two decimal places with FETCH API

Tags: javascript, html, css, fetch-api

I am making a website where it shows the different currency quotes.

I am consuming an API with FETCH, but I already tried adding `.toFix (2)` to it and it has not worked for me to show only two numbers after the comma.

```
function fetchData() {  

fetch("https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales")

  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    const filteredOutput = data.filter(item => {
      switch (item.casa.nombre) {
        case "Dolar Blue":
          return item;
          break;
        default:
          return null;
      }
    })
    let html = "";
    filteredOutput.forEach(item => {

      html += "<p class= \"compra\"><small class= \"compraPrecio\">COMPRA</small><br>  $ " +item.casa.compra + "</p>";
 

    })

    document
      .querySelector('#blueCompra')
      .insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
  });
  }
  
  fetchData();
```

This is my code to currently consume.
Where should I make the arrangement? Does anyone know?

... and my html:

[image: html]

Comment: can you paste your html screenshot how does it looks like

Comment: Can you explain clearly what is the input and how do you want the output to be?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the compra number is actually a String.
The second issue is that it contains a ',' so it cant be simply parsed with `parseInt`.
The solution is as follows:

1. Remove any commas from the compra string
2. Parse the string as an int
3. Format the int as a currency string

I've added comments `// 1.` `// 2.` and `// 3.` for the code corresoponding to the above list items

```js
function fetchData () {
  fetch("https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales")
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    document.querySelector('.loading').remove()
    const filteredOutput = data.filter(item => {
      switch (item.casa.nombre) {
        case "Dolar Blue":
          return item;
          break;
        default:
          return null;
      }
    })
    filteredOutput.forEach(item => {
      let compra = item.casa.compra
      compra = compra.replace(',', '') // 1. ⭐️
      compra = parseInt(compra) // 2. ⭐️
      compra = compra.toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }) // 3. ⭐️
      document.body.innerHTML += '<p><small>COMPRA $' + compra
    })
  })
  
}
fetchData()
```

```html
<span class="loading">Loading...</span>
```